# how can we capture all requests going from JMeter running on Linux?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My test is running on Linux VM via JMeter [command line]. Access logs of apache server shows that few requests didn't reached to it and for few requests, it is giving 400 response [i.e. bad request]

So i wanted to capture all requests going from JMeter and with parameters if possible.

Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do it using [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) tool like:

   ```
   tcpdump -i any -s0 -w /path/to/dump.pcap
   ```

   And once JMeter test finishes open `dump.pcap` file with [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) and inspect packets
2. Alternative option is configure JMeter to save request and response data. It can be done in 2 ways:

   - Add the following lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

     ```
     jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
     jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
     ```
   - pass above properties via -J command-line argument like:

     ```
     ./jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t example.jmx -l example.jtl
     ```

   Once test finishes open resulting `example.jtl` file in JMeter GUI with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - you will be able to see request and response details along with parameters, variables, etc.

References:

- [JMeter Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for the help!