# Not able to get Jmeter's processed requests in windump file

Tags: jmeter

Not able to get Jmeter's processed requests in windump file.

We are trying to analyse performance bottlenecks for REST APIs for which needs to see each request processing cycle hence trying to collected windump and load it in Wireshark. However unable to get processed requests through Jmeter in the windump file. Below is the query used to collect the dump.

```
windump -i 7 -q -w D:\jm-re\dump_7 -n -C 30 -W 10 -U -s 0
```

Trying to follow as suggested in the below answer to analyse results.
[how can we capture all requests going from JMeter running on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044547/how-can-we-capture-all-requests-going-from-jmeter-running-on-linux).

REST API: HTTP POST request with token as header.

Steps followed:
Started collecting dump by issuing above command in Windows system> Run Jmeter 3.1 for 10 users> stop the dump collection> load the file in Wireshark> search for similar requests

Please guide if missing something while collecting data.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get Jmeter requests captured in Windump and able to successfully loaded in Wireshark.
Command:
    windump -i 5 -w D:\jm-re\dump_6_2
Thank you.